# Refusing to print other lines when bison finds an error

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I am parsing a text file from the compiler i created using bison-flex.
When it finds an error tho, it stops printing the next lines of the text.

For error handling i used

```
extern int yylineno;
void yyerror(char *s) {
errors++;


printf("\n Error at line #%d.\n\n",yylineno);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the parser to continue after a syntax error, you must provide at least one `error` production. Otherwise, the bison/yacc error-recovery algorithm is not applied.

See the [bison manual chapter on error recovery](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Error-Recovery) for more details and some simple examples.